# Python - List of Assignments

Tags: python

Is there a way to have

```
statements = [statement1, statement2, statement3, ...]
```

in Python?

I want to be able to do:

```
run statements[i]
```

or:

`f = statements[j]` (where f is a function)

P.S. I want to have a list of assignment statements (lambda would not work) and I rather not create functions. For example:

```
switch = [output = input, output = 2 * input, output = input ** 2]
```

Is there any other way than defining a function for each entry?

Thank you everyone who answered my question.

Comment: Seeing as functions are objects, yes, this is possible... What have you tried?

Comment: Note that you'd have to define `statement1 ... statementn` in advance (`def statement1():...` or use lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to be able to do: `run statements[i]`

well, you can do that by **exec**:

```
statements = ["result=max(1,2)","print(result)"]
for idx in range(len(statements)):
    exec(statements[idx])
print(result)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This answer is the closest to what I was asking considering that it does not require me to define functions. But now is there a way for me to do f=statement to create a function?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Functions are *first-class-citizens* in python: i.e. you could pass them as parameters or even store them in an array.

It is not uncommon to have a list of functions:
You could build a simple registry in python like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

processing_pipeline = []

def step(function):
    processing_pipeline.append(function);
    return function

@step
def step_1(data):
    print("processing step1")

@step
def step_2(data):
    print("processing step2")

@step
def step_3(data):
    print("processing step3")

def main():
    data = {}
    for process in processing_pipeline:
        process(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here the `processing_pipeline` is just a list with functions.
`step` is a so called *decorator*-function, which works like a closure.
The python interpreter adds while parsing the file every decorated `@step` to the pipeline.

And you are able to access the function with an iterator, or via `processing_pipeline[i]`: try adding `processing_pipeline[2](data)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine:

```
def addbla(item):
    return item + ' bla'

items = ['Trump', 'Donald', 'tax declaration']
new_items = [addbla(item) for item in items]
print(new_items)
```

It adds a *political statement* to every item in `items` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a block of statements, use a function.

```
def run_statements():
    func()
    for i in range(3):
        if i > 1:
            break
    extra_func()

run_statements()
```

If you want to choose specific statements from a list, wrap each one in a function:

```
def looper():
    for i in range(3):
        if i>1:
            break

def func():
    print('hello')

statements = [looper, func]
statements[-1]()
```

If your statements are simply function calls, you can put them directly into a list without creating wrapper functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
funcs = [min, max, sum]
f = funcs[0]
funcs[1](1,2,3) # out 3
funcs[2]([1,2,3]) # out 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we've had every other way, I thought I'd toss this out:

```
def a(input):
    return pow(input, 3)

def b(input):
    return abs(input)

def c(input):
    return "I have {0} chickens".format(str(input))

#make an array of functions
foo = [a,b,c]

#make a list comprehension of the list of functions
dop = [x(3) for x in foo]
print dop
```